# TextBox search and retrieving data without button

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I use VS 2010 with C#.NET.. I need a search implementation to the textbox (Not a richtextbox control) in a way that when a user types in string, he gets a relevant list below. Similar to Google search.

Eg: When he states typing 'AS', below the textbox I need 'ASP.NET' and such similar results to come up.

Comment: where do you want to fetch the data from? SQL Databases or a web service?

Comment: I want it from my Database.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax` `AutoComplete` control

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: Hello, I'm getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Do I need to write any code behind file?

Comment: It is well explained in the link. See the properties  `ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"` and `ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"`